# How do I manage my package's readme on npmjs.com?

Tags: node.js, npm, readme

I have very limited experience with actually publishing npm packages, so this is likely a rather amateur question. I was initially under the impression that the readme featured on a package's npmjs.com page was filled by specifying a `"readme"` and/or `"readmeFilename"` field in my package.json. I [recently learned](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3573#issuecomment-19550501) that this is, in fact, entirely incorrect and I shouldn't be touching either of these fields.

With that in mind, how do I control what's displayed on my package page? Is it automatically extracted from a README.md file? If so, will it automatically update if I change the readme and run `npm publish` again? What markdown parser does npm's website use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is on GitHub, you can change your `readme.md` in GitHub. Then you should pull your repository locally.
Then when you run `npm publish` on the latest version, it will take the latest `readme.md` file content.

If for any reason the updated file is not there, you should tag your package as "latest" on npm.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - `npm publish` automatically reads README.md and uses its contents as the package page's readme.